# CakePHP Find Help (Condition)

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the database as follows

```
Name | Area 1 | Area 2
XYZ    200      300
ZUX    0        0
YYZ    100      200
```

What I want to do is, count the number of rows where SUM of (Area 1 and Area 2) is not equal to 0. In the example mentioned, It's 2. (SUM has to be calculated virtually)

I tried to use different ways with Find(); Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$this->Model->find('count', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        '(Area1 + Area2) != ' => 0
    )
));
// returns 2
?>
```

Comment: Missed out that he wanted to know the amount of rows, type `count` is indeed better. Replaced it in my answer as well (had type `all`). Wasn't aware you could append the fields like that btw, kudos.